# Import module from sibling package with absolute import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

How does one use absolute imports from a module of a sibling package?

Package file structure:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── modulea.py
├── b
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── moduleb.py
├── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

Files test.py and a/modulea.py:

```
from b.moduleb import f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

File b/moduleb.py:

```
def f():
    print('hello')
```

This works:

```
% python test.py 
hello
```

This does not:

```
% python a/modulea.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a/modulea.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b.moduleb import f
ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation it should work: http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `__init__.py` in whatever `.` is.

Comment: Does not work for me: http://pastebin.com/KvHBAbMY. What should the import statement in test/a/modulea.py look like?

Comment: What you have should work. Can you ``import sys ; print(sys.path)``?

Comment: In ./test:  
`% echo 'import sys ; print(sys.path)' > test2.py; python test2.py  
['./test', '/usr/lib/python33.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.3', '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-linux', '/usr/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages']`

Comment: Ah ok. Add ``.`` to the PYTHONPATH env var.

Comment: You probably want to craft a proper setup.py and ``python setup.py develop``.

Comment: it is incorrect if `a` and `b` are toplevel Python packages. They are not inside any Python package otherwise you should use `from toplevel.b.moduleb import f` instead of `from b.moduleb import f`. Though I already see `./__init__.py` in the package file structure in the question

Answer (score 1):

Use `python -ma.modulea`.

Running `python a/modulea.py` adds `a` directory to `sys.path` instead of the parent (`.`).

Don't run scripts from inside Python packages directly. See [Traps for the Unwary](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary).